# comparing each line from first file with the entire contents of the second file in java

Tags: java, file, compare

I want to compare each line of my first file with the entire contents of the second file and print the matching results. 
i'm using this code but its coming to the else part and not giving me the result. 
My files are like this

```
file1 - store.txt               file2 - data.txt    

1,CNB,1234                       1001,1234
2,NCD,1567                       1002,1345
3,ABC,1111                       1003,1111
etc etc                          etc etc
```

I want the result to be

```
CNB, 1234
ABC, 1111
```

This is the code I've written:

```
String y = ",", z = ";";

        File file1 = new File("store.txt");
        File file2 = new File("data.txt");

        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
        BufferedReader bfr1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));

        String name1;
        String name2;
        String[] f1, f2;

        try{

        while (bfr1.readLine() != null && bfr.readLine() != null)
        {

            name1 = bfr.readLine();
            name2 = bfr1.readLine();

            f1 = name1.split(y);
            f2 = name2.split(z);


            if (f1[1].equals(f2[1]))
            {
                //System.out.println(f1[0] + f1[1]);
                for(int i=0; i < 1000;i++) {
                    name1 = bfr.readLine();

                name2 = bfr1.readLine();

                 System.out.println(f1[0] + " \t here");
                }

                //System.out.println(f1[0] + " \t here");
               // System.out.println(s1);
            }

            else
            {
            System.out.println("Not equal");
            }
        }

    }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

Thank You all for the help! :)

Comment: What is happening??.. What is your Output?

Comment: Whats logic behind o/p ?

Comment: `while (bfr1.readLine() != null && bfr.readLine() != null)` this reads _and discards_ one line from each file on each iteration through the loop. You are looking at only every second line in both files.  Also the logic in your program is undecipherable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be optimized a lot since as other posters has said, your nesting iterating without keeping track of previous iteration. The number of "line fetch" you require grows **exponentially** with the number of lines, which is really not good at all.

There's also a **logic fault** since you get wrong this comparison `f1[1].equals(f2[1])`; from your expected result I assume you want to compare `f1[2].equals(f2[1])`

The good news here is that you can use two hashmaps to store the result of the two iteration and then just iterate over them once to get your result.

Here is the code, I've not tested it but it should work:

```
private void compareFiles() {
        BufferedReader bfr1 = null;
        BufferedReader bfr = null;
        String split = ",";
        HashMap<String, String> fileCache1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        HashMap<String, String> fileCache2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try {
            File file1 = new File("store.txt");
            File file2 = new File("data.txt");
            bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
            bfr1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));

            String name1;
            String name2;
            String[] f1;
            String[] f2;
            try {
                // read the first file and store it in an Hashmap (first column ignored)
                while (bfr.readLine() != null) {
                    name1 = bfr.readLine();
                    f1 = name1.split(split);
                    fileCache1.put(f1[2], f1[1]);
                }
                // read the second file and store it in an Hashmap (second column useless?)
                while (bfr1.readLine() != null) {
                    name2 = bfr1.readLine();
                    f2 = name2.split(split);
                    fileCache2.put(f2[1], f2[0]); // f2[0] is useless i think
                }

                // iterate once over the first hashmap and compare with the second.
                for (String key1 : fileCache1.values()){
                    if(fileCache2.containsKey(key1)){ // here is your desired match
                        System.out.println(fileCache1.get(key1)+", "+key1); // print or do whatever you want
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                bfr1.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank u so much! But its not working the way i wanted it to!:/

Comment: Then try to explain better what you want to achieve. You just put the expected result, without explaining the logic behind it. My logic implementation is based on an assumption, but it can be easily changed. The real point is to create two hashmaps and THEN compare. You will scan the files once, and then simply iterate over an hashmap which resides in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you read from each file loads of times. You read in the while loop, then you throw that away and read again. Also each time you read from the first file you also read from the second.

You want to read from the second file once and remember that result.

You want to read from the first file once for each time around the loop.

For example:

```
name1 = bfr.readLine();
name2 = bfr2.readLine();

while (name1 != null) {

    // Do stuff with name1 and name2

    name1 = bfr.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition should be like this

```
  //f1[2] = 1234 and f2[1] = 1234
  if (f1[2].equals(f2[1]))
  {
    // Write your logic here
  }
```